# What is the regex expression to find everything between --[[ and ]]?

Tags: python, regex, lua, capture

I'm trying to clean up some Lua code files using a Python script and regex by removing comments. I'm using the following regular regular expression to find multiline comments: `"--\[\[[^]\]]+"`

For example:

```
--[[ This is a comment
on multiple lines
that needs to be removed ]]
```

The expression picks these up without a problem. However, there are also comments like this:

```
      --[[
      if thing == "whatever" or thing == "whateeeever" then
        self:print( ">" .. thing.. params[2] .. " something " )
      -- printing the thing
         ]]
```

On a comment like this, the regex only captures until the first `]` on the end of `params[2]` instead of all the way to `]]`

Can anyone provide me a working regex that captures everything, including square brackets?

Comment: You just need `(?s)--\[\[.*?]]`

Comment: Yeah, this works just as well indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try a pattern like

```
^[^\S\n]*--\[\[.*(?:\n(?!.*\]\]).*)*\n.*\]\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VbnRUn/1)